# New WPF project in visual studio 2010 throws an error

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, visual-studio-2010

I am new to WPF. When I create a new WPF project in Visual Studio 2010 .net framework 4.0. and compile it shows a error message

> Error 1   Could not load type 'Microsoft.Windows.Design.Metadata.FeatureKeyAttribute' from assembly 'Microsoft.Windows.Design.Platform, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'.   c:\users\admin\documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\WpfApplication2\WpfApplication2\MainWindow.xaml    1

Even the designer shows error. How to get away with this error?

Answer (score 0):

It seems like there is a problem with the file structure of your computer. Have you made sure that all of your files that you need are in the folder that Visual Studio is reading from? Go and check by looking in the folder where Visual Studio saves all of the files.

Comment: I had installed visual studio with default settings. WinForms application just works fine.

Comment: I'd just try to reinstall Visual Studio

Comment: Same thing happened to me just check and see of the file "c:\users\admin\documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\WpfApplication2\WpfApplication2\MainWindow.xaml" even exists, if it dosen't I would do what @Mathew said, just reinstall Visual Studio, and I would get the 2013 version not 2010

Answer (score 0):

As Mathew suggested, I re-installed visual studio and problem got resolved.